# Flutter project archive issue using Xcode: agora_rtc_engine "Module 'agora_rtc_engine' not found"

Tags: ios, flutter

[image]

I am using Agora in my flutter application, everything works fine when I test it with simulators/emulators and my android/ios phones.

When I archive the project on Xcode and upload to App store, it throws one error as below, I have searched online for a couple of hours but didn't get any progress. I don't even have any idea what is the issue and what causes the issue

My understanding is `agora_rtc_engine` is installed by Flutter, I am not supposed to do anything when archiving an IOS package.

If anyone knows what happened and what needs to be done, please share your thoughts, Thanks!

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I already opened `runner.xcworkspace` but getting same error

Comment: @Niraj sorry to reply late, to be honest, I haven't figured it out yet...

Comment: Ok, I just run `pod install` on iOS module and it worked.

Comment: @HaifengZhang I’m facing a similar issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @VegetaSaiyan Sorry for the late reply. I cleaned up all the downloaded ios packages and removed the podfile and then install everything again and it works.

Answer (score 3):

From xcode change the ios deployment target to 11.0

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem because I was trying to open and archive `runner.xcodeproj` using `xcode`. When I selected `runner.xcworkspace` I was able to successfully archive.

Answer (score -2):

try "flutter build ios" again

Comment: this is better off as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: why ? @CoderUni even tho it didn't work haha