# i have been getting this error Module 'agora_rtc_engine' not found in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, generated, runner

I have tried every solution but does not work .after i have add firebase_messaging dependency then this error has been come before that agora functionality have working fine .Please help how can i solve this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK52J.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter project archive issue using Xcode: agora\_rtc\_engine "Module 'agora\_rtc\_engine' not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886197/flutter-project-archive-issue-using-xcode-agora-rtc-engine-module-agora-rtc-e)

Comment: I have tried this wasn't  work . i am trying to run  flutter ios  project .actually agora_rtc_engine functionality working fine but after  i have add firebase_messaging this error is getting.

Comment: In pod file dependency doesn't install.please help i have been trying to solve this issue since 3 days .